# Rendering process for SSR React application and async code execution

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

When I'm doing SSR with react, how the content that will be send to client is constructed?

- Does it wait for async actions to be finished?
- Does it wait for state
  of all components in the tree to be stable in some manner?
- Will it wait for async code in some life cycle method like `componentWillMount() ...` decorated with `await/async` code?
- If I will wrap some async code into Promise and will call `setState` it it's callback - will this change be taken into consideration?

Answer (score 1):

It will be simple html as a string that comes out from:

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element)
```

and shall be rendered on browser. Rest all the js bundle which loads from the html will overtake your application as it loads. This is the regular react bundle:

```
<script src="/react-bundle.js"></script>
```

So the server rendered html will be something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
  ...
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root">
     // your server rendered html string shows up here
  </div>
  <script src="/react-bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Promises and async code will not be a part of this rendered html, but if you need to add it, this will require some additional tricks.
Code in componentWillMount will be executed and included in the server rendered string, but methods which trigger after component mounts like componentDidMount shall not have an affect on the server rendered string.

Comment: your answer describes hydration process. I've posted 4 specific questions and you answer doesn't do that. I don't understand what do you mean e.g. with `Code in componentWillMount will be executed and included in the server rendered string`

Comment: @zmii Any code that comes in the way before the first time `render` is triggered will be executed. Now if its something async like setting the state then it shall not reflect in the rendered string. If you just called an action which will update a value in store (in componentWIllMount), then it will also be updated in the rendered string.